# Why are my seeds getting moldy

Tags: houseplants, indoors, seeds, germination, mold

This is the third time that I try to germinate seed, like strawberry raspberry kiwi and stuffs
I put it in glass container with wet cotton balls in it
Instead of the seeds germinate they always get moldy.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

None of strawberries, raspberries, or kiwi fruit are grown commercially from seed. Strawberry plants produce "runners" which can be cut off to start a new plant. Raspberry plants can be dug up and split into smaller pieces to grow into more plants. Kiwi fruit are propagated either by grafting or by taking cuttings.

If you put the seeds or the fruit in an airtight container with plenty of moisture, it is inevitable that mold will grow unless you carefully sterilize everything.

If you want to grow strawberries or raspberries from seed, plant to seed in compost in a pot (which is how seeds germinate naturally, of course). It may take several weeks before the seeds germinate. Keep the compost damp, but not soaking wet.