# Growing kiwi from kiwi slices?

Tags: germination, kiwifruit

After reading various blogs like [How to Grow Tomatoes from Tomato Slices](https://www.greensguru.com/how-to-grow-tomatoes-from-tomato-slices/) I am wondering: **Is it at all possible to grow kiwi seedlings from kiwi slices?** Did anybody try that? What kind of soil is suggested? How warm or humid should it be? What kind of procedure would you recommend?

#### References

- [Why are my seeds getting moldy](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/55390/why-are-my-seeds-getting-moldy/55393#55393)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: **Yes**, it is possible to grow kiwi sprouts from kiwi slices just using normal compost-based soil. But you really need to have patience, moisture the soil every few days and just wait. It took nearly two months, from mid of April until mid of June for the sprouts to become approximately 2cm high.